# I will be graduating a semester early, what schools have spring & summer intake?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters

I have enough credits to graduate a semester early, and will be soon. I know of the perquisites such as the GMAT, but when researching the school I wanted to go to (Fordham) I am worried now that most schools only have a fall intake. I noticed UMaryland has spring intake and Villanova has a summer intake. Will my pool of schools be limited if I want to start in the spring?

Comment: Are you sure graduating early is the best strategy for you, rather than spending the semester at your current school taking more advanced classes in your field? That would let you apply to a wider range of schools for fall intake.

Comment: Another option is to stay at your current school, and do some graduate work as a non-degree student.  Most schools will let you transfer 6-12 hours for master's degree, so it's not a waste of time.  I did it and don't regret it at all.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer if you don't say what sort of degree program you're interested in.  You should never think of issues like this in terms of entire schools, since different degree programs will have different policies.

Answer (score 2):

check the list below for spring intake colleges. dates may be different as the list is for 2015

http://www.hotcoursesabroad.com/india/prepare-to-apply/how-to-apply-to-a-university/usas-spring-2015-admissions/

Comment: Thank you for this, I found it helpful. It seems limited, and I'll be looking for summer intakes as well.

Answer (score 0):

I started in January at UT Austin in 1998 in Aerospace Engineering. I had just graduated from there in December as an undergrad and was already doing research with my eventual PhD supervisor. I don't know if these difference were a factor for me.